# nginx перебрасывает на 81 порт

Tags: nginx

Добрый день. У меня так nginx настроен, как прокси к апачу. То есть nginx на 80 порту, а apache на 81. Вот конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name jamesjgoodwin.ru www.jamesjgoodwin.ru;

    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://jamesjgoodwin.ru$1 permanent;
    }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name jamesjgoodwin.ru www.jamesjgoodwin.ru;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/jamesjgoodwin.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/jamesjgoodwin.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81/;
        index   index.html index.php;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ~* \.(html|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|css|js|pdf|txt|tar|ico)$ {
        root /var/www/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~ /.ht { deny all; }

    if ($http_host ~ "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}") {
        return 444;
    }
}
```

Но почему-то в случае, если я пишу ссылку без слэша в конце, то у меня выбивает ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. И в адресной строке прибавляется :81 к моему сайту, то есть редиректит на 81 порт. Если же ссылку закрывать слэшем, то такого не происходит. Как это поправить?

Comment: `proxy_redirect default;`

Comment: @norbornen не помогло.

Comment: скорее всего проблема в работе apache и/или скриптов, им интерпретируемых. проверьте: `wget -S --spider http://127.0.0.1:81/ссылка-без-слэша`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, вы были правы. Я изменил в конфиге apache строку Listen 127.0.0.1:81 просто на 81 и всё заработало.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. И в адресной строке прибавляется :81 к моему сайту, то есть редиректит на 81 порт.

приведённый фрагмент конфигурации *nginx*, по-моему, не может приводить к подобному результату.

проблема, скорее всего, кроется в конфигурации программы *apache*, слушающей 81-й порт, или работе скриптов, интерпретируемых данным экземпляром программы.

чтобы удостовериться в этом, сравните возвращаемые заголовки, выполнив команды на сервере:

```
$ wget -S --spider http://127.0.0.1:81/ссылка-без-слэша
$ wget -S --spider http://127.0.0.1:81/ссылка-со-слэшем/
```